# Email validation expression allows underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

Email validation expression `/^(?!_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@(?!_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/` allows underscore for some cases, but otherwise works perfectly.

It does not fail the following email address:

```
tets_name@gmail.com
test____name@gmail.com
```

Here is the pattern :

```
var pattern =/^(?!_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@(?!_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;     
if (pattern.test(Email)) {
    return false;
}
```

How can I restrict this to not allow underscore?

Comment: when an answer really solves your guestion mark it as answer.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that `\w` matches ASCII letters (`[A-Za-z]`), digits (`[0-9]`) and an underscore.

To make sure your regex does not match underscores replace all `\w` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and the last `\w{2,3}` can be replaced with `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/
```

If you plan to match emails that only contain single underscores between letters/digits and not at the start/end use

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/
```

See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/05TY60/4) and [another regex here](https://regex101.com/r/05TY60/13).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters/digits
- `(?:[.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `[.-]` - a dot or `-` (no need to escape a dot inside a character class)
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters/digits
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters/digits
- `(?:[.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `[.-]` - a dot or `-` (no need to escape a dot inside a character class)
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters/digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`  - 2 or 3 ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, i just added `.*` in the negative look ahead , you were only looking for single `_` at the start of your string but `-` can be at other postitions

```
^(?!.*_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$
```

[try demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oiMHcP/2)

see explanation on the link